# Grant acces to website through URL key - Forge, Laravel

Tags: laravel, forge, access-rules

I've set access limits to a website i'm developing (and hosting on forge-digital.ocean platforms), by adding url key at the end of it. It looks like [www.websiteaddress.com/\](http://www.websiteaddress.com/%5C)<key>. If you access [www.websiteaddress.com](http://www.websiteaddress.com) (without <key>) you get 503 Service unavailable.
I'm prety sure i've set this from laravel.forge platform, but can find it anymore, and sent an email to them for help, but they say they don't have anything like that.
So, I'm lost now, because I what to delete that rule, and I have no idea from where.
Did anyone come accros this feature/ used it somehow? Give me a map so I can find my way back!
PS. I don't have a lot of experience in web developement, this is my first project deployed.
Thank you!